# Is it haram to swear if you are not insulting?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam

Is it haram to swear if you are not insulting anyone? For example "Today is a (f-word)-ing bad day!" or "Damn it I got a peice of (s-word) on my shoe"

Comment: Yes, foul language is a no-no, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Swearing is considered an **immoral act that is not a trait of a Muslim, regardless of whomever it is directed to.**

Allah says in the Qu'ran:

> يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا لَا يَسْخَرْ قَوْمٌ مِّن قَوْمٍ عَسَىٰ أَن يَكُونُوا خَيْرًا مِّنْهُمْ وَلَا نِسَاءٌ مِّن نِّسَاءٍ عَسَىٰ أَن يَكُنَّ خَيْرًا مِّنْهُنَّ وَلَا تَلْمِزُوا أَنفُسَكُمْ وَلَا تَنَابَزُوا بِالْأَلْقَابِ بِئْسَ الِاسْمُ الْفُسُوقُ بَعْدَ الْإِيمَانِ وَمَن لَّمْ يَتُبْ فَأُولَٰئِكَ هُمُ الظَّالِمُونَ
>
> *O you who believe! (Let) not ridicule a people [of] (another) people, perhaps that they maybe better than them; and (let) not women [of] (other) women perhaps that they maybe better than them.* **And (do) not insult yourselves and (do) not call each other by nicknames.** *Wretched is the name (of) disobedience after the faith. And whoever (does) not repent, then those - they (are) the wrongdoers.*
>
> <sup>[- Quran 49:11](https://quran.com/49/11)</sup>

Our speech reflects our nature and heart,  so even if something is not haram **we should only speak good or say nothing.**

Rasulullah said:

> *“Whoever believes in Allah and the Last Day should*  **speak good or keep silent** *….”*
>
> <sup>- Recorded by Sahih Bukhari and Muslim</sup>

Swearing is commonly used when one is in a situation which disrupts them such as a bird excreting on you. **This is a habit that must be changed.** Instead you should say something like *"Alhamdullilah"*.

Allah says in the Qu'ran:

> قَدْ أَفْلَحَ الْمُؤْمِنُونَ
>   الَّذِينَ هُمْ فِي صَلَاتِهِمْ خَاشِعُونَ
>   وَالَّذِينَ هُمْ عَنِ اللَّغْوِ مُعْرِضُونَ
>
> *“Indeed successful are the Believers, those who in their prayer have Khushoo’ (fear of Allah) and* **those who refrain from vain talk.** *”*
>
> <sup>[- Quran 23:1-3](https://quran.com/23/1-3)</sup>

It is clear that there is a **punishment for those who use foul language.** Just don't do it. The Angels **record everything you say and in the Day of Judgement, Allah will question you on why you use foul language unless you stop immediately and repent.**

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

Here the swear word is being used to express a strong opinion. It's not wrong to express a strong opinion, however it's haram to swear, especially those of a sexual nature.

One could say:

> Today was a terrible day

Or:

> Today was just catastrophic.

Obviously, tone of voice helps.

Answer (score -1):

Islam is a religion of peace if you curse your not spreading peace, but you are going against it. If you think good thoughts about someone than Allah will be pleased. So spread peace not hatred. If you are angry say the dua of being angry. When you hear someone curse say "Astagfirullah" and walk away.